# Blind Via vs. Buried Via

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, layout

Are these two things similar? Online guides overlapped the definition between the two.

From this [website](https://www.pcbcart.com/article/content/glossary-of-terms.html), it states that blind vias are a through-hole that connects inner layers, but it can't be seen from the exterior of the PCB. They defined buried vias as a via connecting a top layer to one or more inner layers.

However, this [website](https://www.exceptionpcb.com/elementor-5110/) proposes swapped meanings for the two terms. It says that blind vias connect the top layer to one or more inner layers and that the buried via is the through-hole that connects inner layers, but it can’t be seen from the exterior of the PCB.

How these two websites define the terms gives me difficulty grasping the idea of them being useful in the PCB. Which offers the best solution?

Comment: The first link has their definitions swapped (pcbcart). There are lots of errors to be found on the Web and books which is why you need to verify the information you read. You can contact them and they will appreciate the correction. The blind hole terminology is used in machining for drill holes that don't go through.

Answer (score 16):

Buried via implies it is "buried" and is not visible

Blind via implies a blind hole, that is it only goes through some layers but starting on an outer layer. A blind hole refers to a hole that is drilled to a specified depth without breaking through to the other side.

[image: Image of PCB through hole, buried via and blind via]

<sub>Image source: [Corelis - Blind and Buried Vias](https://www.corelis.com/blog/blind-and-buried-vias/)</sub>

Comment: This is the convention used by our company (a major aerospace defense contractor) and our pwb vendors.

Comment: Is it true that making single long via that goes through multiple layers is difficult since the holes will not align on all layers and thus if we need to traverse multiple layers in the PCB, we need to use staggered vias?

Comment: @quantum231 - Hi, Please don't ask a new question in a comment. Also note that the answer's author has deleted their account, so they will not be notified of your comment and cannot reply to it. || Please ask a new question and, if relevant, you can link to this one. Thanks. (Your comment above will be deleted shortly,)

Comment: It is a simple yes/no answer. No point in posting a whole new question for a simple yes/no.